# Matching a number pattern in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to find a way to matching the number sequence that I have in one table to a sequence in another table but with different numeric values in SQL if possible.

Example:

```
Table A contains

Word   | Location
-----------------
Quick    2
Brown    3
Fox      4

Table B contains

Word   |  Location  | Product
------------------------------
Quick        2           A
Brown        3           A
Fox          4           A
Brown        8           B
Fox          9           B
Quick        10          B
Quick        7           C
Quick        18          D
Brown        19          D
Fox          20          D
```

Basically I only want to return Product A & D from table B because they are the only ones who have a reference to all three words and importantly those words are in the same ordered sequence ie 2,3,4 being the same as 18,19,20 only with different numeric values.

It is easy to find out all the products which reference all of the words but I only want products which match all of the same words in the correct order.

Note often the order won't be as simple as 2,3,4 it could be 2,7,9 and in which case if a product had all of the words with in an order of 36, 41, 43 I would want it returned.

I hope the above makes sense

Comment: +1 to empathize with such an awkward problem ;-)

Comment: which RDBMS sql server? or Oracle?

Comment: SQL 2012 - I've been banging my head against this for a while now and no joy. I thought I had it by ordering the words by the location asc into a single string and grouping by the product id then doing a PATINDEX however while this returned the product which matched the string it didn't factor in the order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select PRODUCT
from   (
select A.Word,A.Location-B.Location as diff,B.PRODUCT
from   TableA A
join   TableB B
on     A.Word=B.Word)C
group by diff,PRODUCT
having count(*)=3
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3975/3)

Comment: If you change the last line in your fiddle to `('Fox', 21, 'D')` it won't work.

Comment: @ShyJ: Please note this line in the question.. "Note often the order won't be as simple as 2,3,4 it could be 2,7,9 and in which case if a product had all of the words with in an order of 36, 41, 43 I would want it returned."

Comment: Thanks Joe this does appear to work and gives me what I'm after. I did change the = 3 to = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TableA) but apart from that it filters out the records which it should. I'll do a load more testing with different use cases in the next day or so and if I have any more issues I'll flag them. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

The schema and the data:

```
CREATE TABLE A
    (     
     Word varchar(10),
     Location int                  
    );

CREATE TABLE B
    (Word varchar(10),
     Location int,
     Product varchar(3));

INSERT INTO A (Word, Location)
VALUES
  ('Quick', 2),
  ('Brown', 3),
  ('Fox', 4);

INSERT INTO B (Word, Location, Product)
VALUES
  ('Quick', 2, 'A'),
  ('Brown', 3, 'A'),
  ('Fox', 4, 'A'),
  ('Brown', 8, 'B'),
  ('Fox', 9, 'B'),
  ('Quick', 10, 'B'),
  ('Quick', 7, 'C'),
  ('Quick', 18, 'D'),
  ('Brown', 19, 'D'),
  ('Fox', 20, 'D');
```

The query:

```
SELECT Product
FROM B B1
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM B B2
  WHERE B2.Location < B1.Location
    AND B2.Product = B1.Product) = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM A A1 JOIN A A2 ON A1.Word = B1.Word
  WHERE A2.Location < A1.Location)
GROUP BY Product
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A)
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2aaed/1) you can find the SQLFiddle.